# Mojolicious: Passing a Select field HTML Fragment

Tags: perl, mojolicious

This is not super elegant, but I need to glue existing code onto a new Mojolicious application and maintain some backwards compatibility.

In the old application I have some database records:

```
    # hacked in special sql for categories, keep them in order in the drop down
    # 11/7/2011 9999 category number is for folksonomy tags only....
    if ( $table eq 'om_categories' ) {
        my $sqlstring =
"SELECT * FROM om_categories WHERE category != '9999' order by parent,description";
        ( $registry_error, $hash_ref ) =
          sqlraw( $class, $db, $sqlstring, $id, $token );
```

that are then converted into, select HTML entries, used in several places:

```
    if ($object eq 'OmYellowpage') {
    my ( $option_string, $count ) =
          collect_items( 'local', $self->session('db'), 'om_categories', '', 'description', 'select', '' );

        my $select_classification = <<EOT ;
 '<select type="required" name="classification"><option value=\"\"></option>$option_string</select>'\n    
EOT
```

and in the **new** Mojolicious application, I wanted to do this:

```
$self->stash( 'selectclassification',$select_classification ) ;
```

however, probably quite logically, this turns up as escaped valid text in the form, rather than the select that I wanted:

```
&lt;optgroup label=&quot; TRANSPORT&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;1004, 1160,Driving skills&quot;&gt;Driving skills&lt;/option&gt;
```

I've tried various other Mojolicious rendering syntaxes (including partial) but can't find anything that works currently. I don't particularly want to radically rewrite this bit, because the current library will then lose back compatibility. So I'm stuck, I'm relatively new to Mojolicious, too.

[image: Partial screen shot of output]

For the curious, [this is the old project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cclite/)

Comment: *"..this turns up as escaped valid text in the form.."* Can you include a screen shot of that text? And what would be the expected result?

Comment: I've added a sample screenshot of the output, as requested.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but what happens if you remove the opening and closing single quotes from the string you generate in the heredoc (or leave the quotes in, and assign it directly to the variable by losing the heredoc portion)?

Comment: Thanks. I have to concentrate on something else in the next couple of days, but I'll give removing quotes a spin.

Answer (score 3):

You do not show your template. If you use the Mojolicious template engine, note that the default behaviour is with `auto_escape` set.

For details see the [Mojo::Template](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Template) documentation.

That means you will have to use `%==` in your template to get the unescaped content of your stashed variable:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/',
    sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $option_string = '  <optgroup id="eu" label="EU">
           <option value="de">Germany</option>
           <option value="en">en</option></optgroup>';
        my $select_classification = <<EOT ;
          '<select type="required" name="classification">
           <option value=\"\"></option>$option_string</select>'\n    
EOT
        $self->stash( 'selectclassification',$select_classification );
        $self->render(template => 'foo');
    };

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ foo.html.ep

    %==  $selectclassification;
```

You might also want to remove the single quotes as suggested by @stevieb

Comment: Thank you, works a treat and I didn't know that! In fact I had already tried removing the single quotes but gratitude to both of you.